# Advice on OpenERP and Odoo HTTP requests batching

Tags: json, request, odoo, batching

Can anybody please give advice or feedback about past successfully/tentative attempts to apply batching of HTTP requests towards OpenERP/Odoo?

What is wanted to do is... kind of simulating user input towards an OpenERP 7 portal, based on the assumption that all user activities are in one way or another translated into HTTP requests, mainly POST with (IINM) JSON payload.

Can anybody raise your hand if you ever tried to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the same way that the JavaScript client does it, by calling the [/web/dataset/](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/web/controllers/main.py#L880) controller using JSON POST requests. For each call you will need to also pass the `session_id` cookie in the headers or, if you want to automate the DB selection and login, you will need to make two additional requests to set the DB and login. If using only Python Standard Library, I would suggest to build a `urllib2` opener with a cookie jar from [cookielib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cookielib.html). If using 3rd party libraries, I would suggest to use the the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org) library with their [sessions](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) mechanizm.

Or you could just use [OERPlib](https://github.com/osiell/oerplib), which is specifically built to call OpenERP/Odoo via RPC. It uses XML-RPC and/or Net-RPC (legacy) protocols. It supports everything between OpenERP 5.0 and Odoo 8.0.

Update: For Odoo v8.0 and v9.0 you may also use the [odoorpc](https://github.com/osiell/odoorpc) library - it uses JSON RPC calls.

Comment: Most tumbleweed answer ever. :(